# Select in javascript with class instead of id

Tags: javascript

I have this simple script that works great to avoid uploading large files.

I need it to work with Name or class because it won't work with ID `document.getElementById("video573623_upload_field");` because the ID is dynamic, it's a Wordpress theme.

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="video573623_upload_field" class="custom-file-input" multiple="">

<script>

var uploadField = document.getElementById("video573623_upload_field");

uploadField.onchange = function() {
    if(this.files[0].size > 10000){
       alert("File is too big!");
       this.value = "";
    };
};

</script>
```

Comment: **document.querySelector(".custom-file-input");**

Answer (score 1):

Try `var uploadField = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-file-input')[0];`
Previously when you were using getElementByClassName it was returning a reference variable of array, and then you were directly using onChange() on that reference array, maybe that's why it was not working.

`getElementById()` directly returns the element because id is always unique.

Comment: _"Previously when you were using getElementByClassName"_ Where did the OP say that they were using getElementsByClassName?

Comment: @j08691 he did. But question was all messed up and he repeated his code twice and someone had to edit it, some of his comments were also removed from the original question. So you might had missed that part

Comment: Hello Sarthak!

I have tried your solution but unfortunately it doesn't work, thanks anyway for your help

Comment: Can you explain what error you get when you use getElementByClassName('custom-file-input')[0]?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use class name or anything by default in the input, you can add a custom attribute the custom attributes have to start whit "data" example

```
<input data-customfile="custom-upload" />
```

Use `document.getAttribute('data-files')`

To get the element also you can get the value of the attribute if you needed, you can see more info here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Comment: Hello Luis monsalve!

I had already tried this and it didn't work. There are two input files with the same name (files[]) One is for uploading images and the other for videos

Also thanks for your help

Comment: Ok i understand, I have another idea I will edit my answer